# I can't get background-image to work

Tags: css

I am trying to load in a simple background image but it is driving me daft trying to load it in. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css"> 


</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The background image is in the directory in images/bg.png as stated above in the css.

Comment: is your CSS directory also in `images`? because otherwise youd need to do `url('../images/bg.png')`, or whatever your relative reference is from the CSS folder.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/DFS7c/1/

Comment: I'll make it an answer so you can provide the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference needs to be relative to your CSS directory, not your page location:

```
html { 
  background: url('../images/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Assuming that your images folder is the same depth on the tree as your CSS folder, this should work for you.

Answer (score -2):

it depends where you image is , if you are using a browse select should pop up as you type and you can search through your computer for the image. If not then you can copy this for example 
:

[image]